# Remove and reinstall Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

Right now, I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop. I've been learning through trial-and-error, so I've inevitably made some irreversible blunders I shouldn't have (Deleting my repository list, uninstalling software installer, I did something Xen related so that it takes 2 minutes to open the computer and 5 minutes to connect to the Internet, there're about five error messages every time I open the computer, updates install wrong and screw up the operating system, I deleted my downloads folder, I applied the command `rm * -r` for my whole computer which deleted some things which shouldn't have been deleted, ...).

I want to go back to no operating system (UEFI BIOS) and re-install everything. I've gone on to my tablet and downloaded Ubuntu 14.10 onto a thumb-drive. There's just one problem. When I stick the thumb-drive in and reboot the computer, because of something I've done with Xen, it won't recognize the USB port and keeps on going like normal!

How do I wipe the hard drive and start from scratch?

Comment: Are you able to get into the UEFI? Have you already disabled booting to your hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is different if your system is dual booted with windows.  Many on this site seem to insist dual boots are normal as opposed to a generally bad idea. If you merely wish to replace Ubuntu with a fresh installation your best bet is to boot to a live boot cd/dvd/usb and select the installation choice "use the entire drive".

I probably don't need to tell you to backup your valuable data first, but in case I do need to tell you... there I'm telling you!  ;-)